# Form data is not getting inserted in mysql database. I am using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add-todo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAddToDoPage(ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute("todo", new ToDo());
    return "add-todo";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add-todo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addToDo(ModelMap model, @Valid ToDo todo, @ModelAttribute("todo") Date targetdate, @ModelAttribute("todo") String description, BindingResult result){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "todo";
    }
    todo.setUserName(getLoggedInUserName(model));
    todo.setTargetDate(targetdate);
    todo.setUserDescription(description);
    toDoService.saveToDo(todo);
    return "redirect:/list-todo";
}

<form action="#" th:action="@{/add-todo}" th:object="${todo}" method="POST">
                    <td> <input type="number" th:field="*{id}" /> </td>
                    <td> <input type="date" th:field="*{targetdate}"/> </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" th:field="*{description}"/> </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" th:field="*{username}"/> </td>

                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add TODO</button></td>
 </form>
```

I am using the above form and controller.System Date is inserted instead of the date inputted from form while description is not getting inserted in the database.

Comment: Why do you have multiple ModelAttribute with the same name?

Comment: I am new in spring-boot. Can you please suggest the required changes?